# unrecognized selector sent to instance when accessing content from another tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with three tab bar controllers:  Map, Favorite and Setup

[image]

The Map view controller has a flag which is set in the setup view controller.  I navigate between these three controller using the tab bar.

In the Map.h file:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL flag;
```

In the Map.m file:

```
@synthesize flag = _flag;
```

In the Setup.h file:

```
@interface SetupTableViewController :   UITableViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
}


@property (nonatomic) BOOL config;
@property (retain, nonatomic) MapViewController *mapVC;
```

In the Setup.m file I try to read what the flag is set to in the map view controller so I can set my display accordingly.  For ease of debugging I simplified the crash to the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    //Grab the pointer to the first tab bar controller so I can get the configuration
    self.mapVC = (MapViewController *) [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    if (self.mapVC) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad for SetupTVC showCelcius is %d", self.mapVC.flag);      //CRASH
    }
}
```

2014-06-19 13:36:44.495 myApp[25505:60b] -[UINavigationController flag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d43f340
2014-06-19 13:36:44.497 myApp[25505:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController flag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d43f340'

Comment: It looks like that your map view controller is embedded in UINavigationController, is it your case ?

Comment: @Limon yes that is correct, let me update the map.h file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the first object of your self.tabBarController.viewControllers is UINavigationController.
I think that your MapVC is embedded in UINavigationController.
Check that.

If so, then :

```
UINavigationController *mapNC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers.firstObject;
self.mapVC = (MapViewController *)mapNC.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

Comment: Yes that is the case, so then how would I go about to access that from a view controller hierarchy.  Do I cast it to a UINavigation controller and then access the viewcontroller

Comment: UINavigationController *nVC = (UINavigationController *)  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    self.mapVC = (MapViewController *) [nVC.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Based on your feedback, I tried the code snippet I posted above, it makes a lot of assumptions about location of view controllers at index 0 or first object.  Is there a more robust way?

Comment: If your mapVC is root view controller of navigation controller of his navigation hierarchy, then the first object of viewControllers array of that navigationController always is root view controller (mapVC in your case)